# SSH config host match port

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh

I have a server that has multiple "SSH daemons" running (actually Stash and OpenSSH), with different SSH keys needed for each. These daemons are listening on 2 different ports.

In the SSH config on clients (specifically `~/.ssh/config`), is it possible to specify the port in the `Host`/`Match` directive (or some other way), so that I can override the `IdentityFile` based on port? That way `ssh myserver -p 22` and `ssh myserver -p 23` will both login using the correct keys, without additional configuration.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If your ssh client is new enough, you can use the config file `Match` keyword to have conditional configuration based on the target port.

```
Match host somehost exec "test %p = 42"
IdentityFile ...
```

The above example would only apply the "IdentityFile" line if the target host is "somehost" and the target port is 42. `Match` works like `Host` in that the lines following it (up to the next Match or Host line) only apply to sessions which match the criteria. In the example, the Match line checks that the host is "somehost", and it also runs an external command which is deemed to match if the command exits with status 0.

The command being run here is `test %p = 42`. "%p" will be replaced by the port value that ssh would use up to that point (either the default of 22 or the value from the command line). `test` is also known as `[`; it's a command-line utility mostly used in shell scripts as part of an `if` statement. Here, `test` is being used to test if the port number is 42.

The `Match` ssh_config keyword was added to OpenSSH in version 6.5 or 6.6. Check your `ssh_config` man page to see if it's available on your system.

Comment: Oh wow! That's awesome. I assume it's pretty slow though. For a small amount of config using this though, probably not a big deal if it's a little slow.

Comment: I doubt the test takes any appreciable amount of time when compared to ssh crypto handshake.

Answer (score 6):

You can create host "aliases" of sorts in your `~/.ssh/config` file that refer to SSH daemons on different ports of the same server. For example:

```
Host daemon1
HostName host.domain.com
Port 22
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_daemon1

Host daemon2
HostName host.domain.com
Port 23
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_daemon2
```

Then you can run `ssh daemon1` or `ssh daemon2` to log into a particular SSH daemon.

Comment: Yeah, I had that idea too, but it needs to be transparent because there are a large number of deployment scripts that reference the hosts directly (which, I agree, should be parametarised but... yeah)